# Adding ship to and bill to address while order placing with SAP B1 DI Server OrdersServices

Tags: sap-business-one-di-api

I looked for documentation regarding OrdersServices in SAP B1 SDK help files, but unfortunately, they haven't mentioned anything about this service.

I want to add ship to and bill to addresses under the logistics tab in SAP B1 sales order using DI services, these addresses will be there in the sales order document, but not in business partner master data.

How can I do that?

Any link to OrdersServices of DI Server is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add your billto address as

```
<Address><'YOUR ADDRESS HERE'></Address>"
```

and shipto address as

```
<Address2><'YOUR ADDRESS HERE'></Address2>"
```

in your xml.